# Intermittent error while downloading blobs in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my web app running on Azure, I seem to be getting these errors in the windows event logs roughly once 10 minutes while the site is under heavy load

```
The server encountered an unknown failure: The operation has timed out
Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.RequestWithRetry.RequestWithRetrySyncImpl[TResult](ShouldRetry retryOracle, SynchronousTask`1 syncTask)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob.DownloadByteArray(BlobRequestOptions options)
```

But its not all the time, just every now and then, I really dont know how to diagnose it or even find out why this could be occurring.

Can I provide you with some sample code? What would you need to see? Unfortunately, this app is under NDA so I cannot talk about specifics or give to much away.

I have cross posted this on the MS forums as well, and I will share all answers I get on any site. This is a real production issue at the moment and any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that these errors occur when under heavy load. There are a few factors that could result in intermittent errors against Storage:

- Network bandwidth. You get approx. 100Mbps per core. Could you be saturating the network bandwidth between compute and storage? I'm guessing you have multiple role instances, which would reduce the likelihood of hitting this particular issue.
- Per-item throughput and transaction rate. Each blob, effectively stored in its own partition, has a target of 60MB/s. Do you have multiple readers of the same objects? If so, it's possible you're hitting timeouts due to too many readers requesting the same object, either in throughput or in transaction count (each object has a target of 500 transactions / second).
- Per-account transaction rate. A storage account has an overall scale target of 5,000 transactions per second. Access enough blobs simultaneously, and you could potentially exceed this limit.

More details on scalability targets [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx).

Comment: how on earth do you measure this? from what I can see there is really no way to track how much you are using per instance? the APIs are quite limiting.

Comment: Storage Analytics will give you details on every single blob access, exact time stamps, uri's, etc. It will also provide hourly rollups. See [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343270.aspx) to see how to enable and access storage analytics.

Comment: Further, you can measure network utilization with a perf counter. Maybe a simple calculation like `Nic Utilization = ((Total Bytes\Sec * 8)/current bandwidth) * 100` to get percentage of network used per instance. Perf counters are stored in one table, representing all instances, with instance id in one of the fields. You can then query to discover % utilization.

Comment: perhaps, but usually with transaction/transfer limits you get runtime exceptions don't you?

Comment: I have no idea of the root cause of your issue. I was simply pointing you toward ways of narrowing things down (or eliminating suspects). There are indeed exceptions related to Storage, but since you were receiving timeouts, I thought it might help to at least understand whether you're hitting some threshold.